# May I ask why I’m getting this error in C

Tags: c

Can I get some help to fix it? I already did the code myself but I’m not sure how to fix this error.

> error: invalid operand to binary * (have 'int' and 'int *')

```
#include <stdio.h>



void pay_amount (int dollars, int *twenties, int *tens, int *fives, int *ones);


int main(void)
{
  int amount, twenties, tens, fives, ones, reduced_amount;

  pay_amount( amount, &twenties, &tens, &fives, &ones);


  printf("\n");   /* blank line */

  printf("$20 bills: %d\n", twenties);
  printf("$10 bills: %d\n", tens);
  printf(" $5 bills: %d\n", fives);
  printf(" $1 bills: %d\n", ones);

  return 0;
}


void pay_amount (int dollars, int *twenties, int *tens, int *fives, int *ones)
{

  int reduced_amount;

  printf("Enter a dollar amount: ");
  scanf("%d", &dollars);

  *twenties = dollars / 20;
  reduced_amount = dollars - (20 * twenties);

  *tens = reduced_amount / 10;
  reduced_amount = reduced_amount - (10 * tens);

  *fives = reduced_amount / 5;

  *ones = reduced_amount - (5 * fives);

}
```

Comment: It has to be `20 * (*twenties)` and `10 * (*tens)` and `5 * (*fives)`.  You have to dereference the pointers.

Comment: Next time also mention the line number, and other relevant information that potentially can help us diagnose your problem.

Comment: Sorry I included a gyazo image showing the line number and everything but it was changed I guess.

Comment: Right – someone edited your question and removed it. Do not post images of errors! (And it did not mention the line number...)

Answer (score 0):

`twenties`, `tens`, etc. are pointer type. You need to dereference the pointer types when you do calculation:

```
void pay_amount (int dollars, int *twenties, int *tens, int *fives, int *ones)
{

  int reduced_amount;

  printf("Enter a dollar amount: ");
  scanf("%d", &dollars);

  *twenties = dollars / 20;
  reduced_amount = dollars - (20 * (*twenties));

  *tens = reduced_amount / 10;
  reduced_amount = reduced_amount - (10 * (*tens));

  *fives = reduced_amount / 5;

  *ones = reduced_amount - (5 * (*fives));

}
```

Comment: @hibinohareluya No worries!

Answer (score 0):

You have a int pointer and a regular int. You should be doing operations on just the int.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Pointers variables, when you write the variable name of the Pointer you are actually mean the address (Pointer stores an address), so you need to use the operator * to get to the data within that variable. Example -
*(pointer).